# dump() in R not source()able- output contains "..."

Tags: r, dump

I'm trying to use dump() to save the settings of my analysis so I can examine them in a text editor or reload them at a later date.
In my code I'm using the command

```
dump(ls(), settingsOutput, append=TRUE)
```

The file defined by `settingsOutput' gets created, but the larger objects and locally defined functions are truncated.  Here's an excerpt from such a file.  Note these files are generally on the order of a few kb.

```
createFilePrefix <-
function (runDesc, runID, restartNumber) 
{
  ...
createRunDesc <-
function (genomeName, nGenes, nMix, mixDef, phiFlag) 
{
  ...
datasetID <-
"02"
descriptionPartsList <-
c("genomeNameTest", "nGenesTest", "numMixTest", "mixDefTest", 
"phiFlagTest", "runDescTest", "runIDTest", "restartNumberTest"
  ...
diffTime <-
structure(0.531, units = "hours", class = "difftime")
dissectObjectFileName <-
function (objectFileName) 
{
  ...
divergence <-
0
```

Just for reference, here's one of the functions defined above

```
createFilePrefix <- function(runDesc, runID, restartNumber){
    paste(runDesc,  "_run-", runID, "_restartNumber-", restartNumber, sep="")
}
```

Right now I'm going back and removing the problematic lines and then loading the files, but I'd prefer to actually have code that works as intended.

Can anyone explain to me why I'm getting this behavior and what to do to fix it?

Comment: That is strange.  `dump(rep("read.table", 10), file)` works fine for me.  Can you show one of the complete function definitions?

Comment: @RichScriven done!

Comment: Why are you using `dump` instead of `save`?